# Variable in \foreach,

Tags: tikz-pgf, loops, pgffor

I would like to show you my problem. Here you have the script to generate a picture.Now I need to generate a second picture in which the arrows are not equally spaced any more.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz} %for drawings
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tkz-fct} %for functions
\usepackage[hmargin=1in,vmargin=1in]{geometry}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
 every path/.style = {},
 every node/.append style = {font=\sffamily}
 ]



% Store points unrolled
  \foreach \x in {0,30,60,...,330}
  {
   \node at (\x /30 , 0) (P1\x) {};
   \node at (\x /30+ 1,0) (P2\x) {};
   \draw[lightgray] (P1\x)  -- (P2\x) {};

  };

% Store vorticity points
 \foreach \x in {0,30,60,...,330}
  { 

   \node at ($(P1\x)!1cm+0.6cm*sin(\x)!90:(P1\x)$) (V1\x) {};
   \node at ($(P2\x)!1cm+0.6cm*sin(\x+30)!270:(P2\x)$) (V2\x) {};

  };

% Draw the vorticity distribution
 \foreach \x in {0,30,60,...,330}
 {
  \draw[very thick, <-] (V1\x)  -- (P1\x) node(xline)[right] {};
  \draw[very thick, <-] (V2\x)  -- (P2\x) node(xline)[right] {};
  \draw[lightgray] (V1\x)  -- (V2\x) node(xline)[right] {};
  \draw[lightgray] (V1\x)  -- (V2\x) node(xline)[right] {};

 }


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\caption{An example of vorticiy distribution along the N panels when the   geometry is unrolled}
\label{Vorticity_distribution_unrolled}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

would anyone be able to generate a figure describing the same function f=f(\x), but with an higher arrow density where the arrows are higher?

I hope that this question is more understandable.

And thanks a lot.

Dario

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Can you please cut your code down to a  [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). There is too much extra code here that is not relevant to your question - and which doesn't compile. This makes it much easier for people to help you - an much more likely that they will!

Comment: I hope that now is more clear!!!

Answer (score 4):

Based on Symbol 1's answer I have developed the following where the arrow density is higher where the arrows are higher instead of random.

```
\documentclass[border=9,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten <=2,shorten >=2]
    \coordinate (A) at (0, 0);
    \coordinate (B) at (0, 1);
    \draw[->] (A) -- (B);
    \foreach \i [evaluate={\x=\lastx+0.25-(\lasty-1)/3}, evaluate={\y=1+sin(72*\x)/4}, remember=\x as \lastx (initially 0), remember=\y as \lasty (initially 1)] in {1, ..., 60} {
        \coordinate (C) at (\x, 0);
        \coordinate (D) at (\x, {\y});
        \draw[->] (C) -- (D);
        \draw[gray] (A) -- (C) coordinate (A);
        \draw[gray] (B) -- (D) coordinate (B);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

For more information about the `\foreach` command see [tikz documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) section VII.83 "Repeating Things: The Foreach Statement". Options to customize the foreach-statement are described on page 904.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[border=9,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\tikz[shorten <=2,shorten >=2]{
    \draw[->](0,0)coordinate(A)
             (0,1)coordinate(B)
             (A)->(B);
    \foreach\i[evaluate={\x=\i/4-rnd/10;}]in{1,...,20}{
        \draw[->](\x,0)coordinate(C)
                 (\x,{1+sin(72*\x)/4})coordinate(D)
                 (C)->(D);
        \draw[gray](A)--(C)coordinate(A);
        \draw[gray](B)--(D)coordinate(B);
    }
}
\end{document}
```

[image]